# Command \pod with \frac argument dives too small parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

If I use \pod or \pmod command with \frac argument the parenthesis around \frac is too small. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
 a\equiv{b}\pod{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\[
 a\equiv{b}\pmod{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are eXtended versions made using `mathtools`, all the `@` code is copied from the `\pod` and `\pmod` definitions in `amsmath.sty`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\podX[1]{\if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi}(){}{#1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\pmodX[1]{\if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi}(){}{{\operator@font mod}\mkern6mu#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  a\equiv{b}\pod{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\[
  a\equiv{b}\podX*{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\[
  a\equiv{b}\pmod{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\[
  a\equiv{b}\pmodX*{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]